# Do I need a visa? Seeking an Internship for Less than 90 Days in Germany

Tags: visas

Hi I am a student from the US and am seeking an internship in Germany. From this article, it looks like I will not need a visa

https://www.germany-visa.org/training-internship-visa/

Is that true?

Comment: Be aware that that is not the official web site. The official web site for the German embassy in the United States is [germany.info](https://www.germany.info/).

Comment: Your question should be asked on Expatriates Stack Exchange since an internship is closer to working than to tourism.